# How can I improve this code in such a way that it is more adherent to functional style?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am pretty new in TypeScript and moreover in **RxJS** and I have the following doubts about how to improve my functional style.

I have the following piece of code that works fine, but I think that it is ugly as hell and that can be improved from a functional perspective.

Somewhere in my code I declare this array that will contains a list of people name, so each element of this array will be a string:

```
this.peopleStr = [];
```

Somewhere else in my code (into the Angular component **ngOnInit()** method) I call the **getAllPeople()** method from a service to retrieve the list of all people. Each element of the **this.people** list is an object containing several fields (like "name", "surname", "complete_name", etcetc). Then I have to use the **complete_name** field of each object into the retrieved **people** list to populate a new **peopleStr** array that will contain only the string values of the **complete_name** field of each object of the **people** list:

```
this.usersService.getAllPeople().then(people => {
  this.people = people;
  console.log("RETRIEVED PEOPLE: ", people);

  this.people.map(person => {
    this.peopleStr.push(person.complete_name);
  });

  console.log("PeopleStr list: ", this.peopleStr);
    //console.log("PERSON: ", person.complete_name));
  this.loading = false;
});
```

}

So basically, as you can see in the previous code snippet, I have done:

1. I retrieved the previous **people** list from the service.
2. I am iterating on this **people** list using the **map()** operator (and here the first doubt: is a good choice use the **map()** operator for this pourpose or is it better use a classic for loop or something like this?)
3. For each element into the **people** list I push the **complete_name** value (a string) of the current element into my **peopleStr** array.

It works fine but I am asking if there are better approach for this problem. Maybe using the RxJS **pipe()** operator (that for me is pretty hard do understand...)

What could be a neater and more elegant approach to solve this problem using the functional style?

Comment: This is the mother of all opinion-based questions... And the controversies begin right in the question itself: is "functional" indeed "more elegant"? Is it "better" to push functional techniques into a TypeScript codebase where imperative works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map` should be used when you want to create a new array by transforming all elements of an existing array, and when you *use the return value* (the transformed array that `.map` returns).

Here, the right method would be to return the new value for each array item inside the `.map` callback, and use the `.map`'s return value as the `peopleStr`:

```
this.usersService.getAllPeople().then(people => {
  this.people = people;
  this.peopleStr = people.map(person => person.complete_name);
  this.loading = false;
});
```

`.map` is never appropriate when all you want is to iterate over an array with side-effects, since `.map` will result in (confusingly) creating an extra array which doesn't get used. For generic iteration, when you can't find a more appropriate array method to use, use `for..of` or `.forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Using rxjs:

```
this.people$ = this.usersService.getAllPeople();
this.peopleStr$ = this.people$.pipe(map(p => p.complete_name));
```

Second observable automatically updates from first via pipe operator.

Now use both of these observables in your template via async pipe.